# Transition to the GameScene from TitleScene takes time in Swift Spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

The problem I'm having now is that I cannot fix the issue with delay in transition. I figured out that when I try to transition to the `GameScene` from the Title scene for the first time, the scene wont transition smoothly and lags. I surmise it is due to loading the `SKSpriteNodes` and Textures. 
When I remove the code below from the `didMoveToView` in my project, the transition will go smoothly but are there any way to make the transition go smoothly without removing them ? Since I'm new to SWIFT & spritekit some tips or examples will help ! I would love to hear from you !

```
 //setting up the score related materials 
        scoreLabel.text = "x 0"
        scoreLabel.fontSize = 20
        scoreLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = .Left
        scoreLabel.fontColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
        scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x:self.size.width/6, y: self.size.height-35)
        self.addChild(scoreLabel)
        scoreLabel.zPosition = 2


        let pt = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "points")
        pt.position = CGPoint(x:self.size.width/9, y: self.size.height-25)
        self.addChild(pt)
        pt.zPosition = 2

        let life = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "life")
        life.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height-25)
        self.addChild(life)
        life.zPosition = 2

        //setting up the Misses related materials
        missLabel.text = "x 3"
        missLabel.fontSize = 20
        missLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = .Left
        missLabel.fontColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
        missLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2 + life.size.width, y: self.size.height-35)
        self.addChild(missLabel)
        missLabel.zPosition = 2
```

Comment: Read it https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/DesigningGameswithSpriteKit/DesigningGameswithSpriteKit.html if you have no do it yet. In your case: do not place the much set of nodes directly on the Scene. Try to create one parent layer for single logical set of nodes and add nodes to this layer.

Comment: Thank you, I read the developers documents, however ,I find it hard to perceive unlike android's documents.  Since , I'm a noob ,  Some easy example will save me.  And by the way, What does it mean to create one parent layer and add the nodes ?

Comment: I mean that you have some nodes (`SKSpriteNode` objects which represent clouds flying in the sky for example) and you need add it to Scene. The best way will be create one node `Sky` add it to `SKScene` and your clouds nodes add to `Sky` node like `self.sky.addChild(cloudNode)`. In this case your scen object will contain only one direct child node, that will contain other nodes you need for this solution

Comment: Do you mean that you have to  create a empty Node like `let world = SKNode()` and then add the it to the scene `self.addChild(world)` ,`self.world.addChild(pt)`? If so I have no clue what to do since it's not working....

Comment: No, i meen that you 'world' would be the SKSpriteNode , not SKNode and you need to init it with all nesossory params